# ¿Cómo separo las palabras y las imprimo en diferentes lineas en python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Necesito separar las palabras e imprimirlas en diferentes lineas. Con este código separa las letras y las imprime en diferentes lineas:

```
palabras=raw_input("ingrese la frase: ")
for word in palabras :
    print word
```

esto imprime:

```
h
o
l
a
 
m
u
n
d
o
```

lo que necesito que imprima es:

```
hola
mundo
```

Comment: `palabras.split()`

Comment: Puedes poner palabras.split() y dentro de los paréntesis en el char en donde se hace la separación. En este caso un espacio para separar las palabras ' '.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías convertir en una lista la frase que insertes donde cada uno de los elementos sean cada una de las palabras que insertes.

```
palabras = input("Ingrese una frase: ")

lista_de_palabras = palabras.split(' ')

for palabra in lista_de_palabras:
   print(palabra)
```

- En este caso, el split no es necesario pasarle como parámetro un espacio en blanco entre comillas ya que es el por defecto.

La función split básicamente separa lo que insertes como string utilizando un "field separator" por así decirlo, de esta forma el separador de cada palabra será lo que indices. Un ejemplo con otro caracter:

```
>>> ejemplo_con_guion = "Hola-mundo-es-una-prueba"
>>> lista_de_ejemplo = ejemplo_con_guion.split('-')
>>> print(lista_de_ejemplo)
['Hola', 'mundo', 'es', 'una', 'prueba']
```

En este caso hemos creado la lista a partir de la separación de una frase por el separador guión '-'.

Al recorrer la lista podrás imprimir con la salida deseada:

```
>>> for palabra in lista_de_ejemplo:
...     print(palabra)
Hola
mundo
es
una
prueba
```